# Declaring a global variable in a non-member function

Tags: c++

Can I declare a global variable inside a non-member function?

Or in other words, a static equivalent for a non-member function?

And I'd like the variable to not be const - e.g. modifiable...

Comment: What's a "free function"?

Comment: Not a member of a class...

Comment: @Lundin: A common shorthand for "non-member function".

Comment: I think that *standalone* is a better term than *free*. Perhaps rephrase the question depending on what other folk think?

Comment: Aha. Never heard the term before, actually. It made me associate to `free()`. Non-member seems like a better name to use.

Comment: I think we all got there with a few edits. Good question by the way, +1.

Comment: The equivalent I was looking for is `static`... So much for a good question. But thanks for support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I declare a global variable inside a non-member function?

You can provide a declaration for a namespace level *global* variable inside a function. But I have the feeling that you are looking for something else and did not get the wording quite right:

> Or in other words, a static equivalent for a non-member function?

You can declare (and define) a local static variable in a function. The lifetime of which will extend beyond the execution of the function (i.e. the variable will be there for the next function execution and so on).

```
int nextValue() {
    static int counter = 0;
    return ++counter;
}
```

Note that this is not a *global*, as *global* implies accessibility from any context and this variable is only accessible within `nextValue`.

> And I'd like the variable to not be const - e.g. modifiable...

This is completely orthogonal to where you declare/define a variable.

Comment: There's one subtle difference. Local static variables are (more) lazily initialized; global variables are initialized before the first function of the given translation unit is called.

Comment: @MSalters: correct, although the standard provides some leeway for lazy initialization of globals, but compilers tend to do that before `main` anyways. This is equivalent only in as much as the variable lifetime is not bound to a single function call.

Answer (score 6):

You can *declare* a global variable inside a function:

```
void f() {
    extern int i;
}
```

But you'll also need to *define* it in the surrounding namespace, if you want to use it.

Being global, the definition doesn't have to be the same translation unit, but is subject to the One Definition Rule.

If, as indicated in the comments, you actually want a persistent local variable, initialised the first time the function is called, then that's exactly how a local static variable behaves:

```
void f() {
    static int i = whatever();  // initialised the first time
    i = something_else();       // the new value is preserved for next time
}
```

Comment: My understanding was that `const` variables are really nice in that they are shared across function calls. There is a slight penalty because I believe initialization is checked every time the function is run (initialized on first call, not on startup, which seems superior to globals in my case).... So I guess for non-const the best equivalent would be a smart pointer outside the function, and to then check and if needed initialize it?

Comment: @Cookie: I have the feeling that you have some issues with the wording in your question. Instead of using well defined terms with a possible different meaning, you might be better off by describing what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry. Your answer is spot on though.

Comment: @Cookie: I think you mean `static`, not `const`. Static locals are indeed initialised the first time the program reaches them, giving the slight penalty you describe. If you want that kind of "lazy" initialisation, then use a local static, rather than trying to implement it yourself as you describe.